# Is (the proof of) Fermat's last theorem completely, utterly, totally accepted like $3+4=7$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

If a mathematician would/does make use of Fermat's last theorem in a proof in a publication, would s/he still make use of some kind of caveat, like: "assuming Fermat's last theorem is true" or "assuming the proof is correct", or would it be considered *totally* unnecessary to even explicitly mention that the theorem is used?

I assume that the theorem is beyond (reasonable?) doubt, but is it *so much* beyond doubt that it can be used for anything else as well? (E.g., has *the proof* been checked by a computer? If such a thing is possible.)

(Is there even such a thing as a degree of belief in a proof? Perhaps based on length and complexity? Or is it really a binary thing?)

Comment: I'd say it's at least very widely accepted - there are surely *some* people who reject that, but you going to find those for every theorem. However, people often seem to have a certain *minimalistic* approach regarding the facts they use in their proofs - especially if these facts have very complicated proofs. So there are probably quite a few people who won't use fermat's last theorem in a proof, unless there's no way around it, even though they *don't* doubt the correctness of the proof. It's question of elegance and using fermat's theorem might feel like using a sledgehammer.

Comment: I think there is such a thing as degree of belief in a proof, because there could always be some unnoticed mistake (this has happened throughout history). In the case of FLT, this has actually been checked and understood by such a vast number of people in comparison to most proofs that I'd have as much confidence in it as something like the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I would definitely not make that type of caveat which would probably be perceived as quite insulting to those that have checked the proof.

Comment: A valid and sound proof is 100% true.  The problem is that you generally have difficulty convincing people that the arguments are valid.  In fact, it's sometimes easy to "prove" something which seems valid but it turns out one of the justifications was incorrect or perhaps only partially true.  And yes, there is research in the area of automated theorem proving: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving

Comment: This is a rather interesting question, and the problem is, against the comment by Matt, that the number of people that has **actually understand and can follow all the way** the proof by Wiles and Taylor is rather pretty small, *even* among professional mathematicians. It requires huge ammounts of knowledge and depth in very intrincated, complex and specialized areas  that most cannot follow its development. In fact, once I read somewhere (latter I'll try to find it) that it is highly doubtable that more than 100 people really understand the proof...

Comment: @Jared Thanks for bringing up the subject of automated theorem proving.  I would say that automated proof *checking* is sufficient to engender confidence, and there happens to be a recent ACM [article on this](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2014/4/173219-formally-verified-mathematics/fulltext).  Apparently proof verification has progressed far enough in a fairly short time to verify Feit-Thompson.  I'd guess that FLT/modularity is still a ways off, but the rate of progress is encouraging.

Comment: @DonAntonio Suppose only 100 people really understand it. Wouldn't you agree that 100 people is way more than most proofs that come out? Most theorems are fairly insignificant and the person that wrote it plus maybe a referee plus maybe 1 or 2 other people read them. The prominence and significance of FLT makes it much more widely read and understood than most other theorems proved in the last 50 years (also the Taylor-Wiles part is pretty "basic" stuff by today's standards, I'm not referring to the full modularity theorem).

Comment: "Most than most proofs that come out", @Matt ? I don't really think so...and who reads them and who  can understand them and get interested in them are, imo, two different things. FLT is known by any mathematician and its proof is as interesting and amazing as anyone can ever expect in this field, yet very few can achieve this goal...yet. Perhaps later a simplified version of it will make it more widespread.

Comment: Maybe it will be like Einstein's relativity theory. A hundred years back, there was the joke that only 3 people worldwide could understand it, but I remember my analysis professor saying that it is mathematically trivial (nowadays). I conjecture that in 50 years, Fermat's last theorem will be a two-line proof, taught to college students.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think maybe you are underestimating the amount of math research done every year. The Math Reviews (which only reviews actual published stuff!!) puts up about 86,000 publications per year. I assure you *most* of that is vetted by far less than 100 people. In the context of the question, one would never write "if this result is true" of those published papers read by maybe one other person, and hence one would definitely not write that for FLT which has been vetted much more thoroughly.

Comment: Which raises the question about how many theorems produced each year are actually false (or whose proof is false). And what the consequences of this are (probably none). Having an economics background, I've often wondered how many results derived in economics papers are actually false (I'd assume quite a few) - and this should have consequences, because economics is an applied science.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the proof is accepted, and it would be bizarre to write "assuming Fermat's Last Theorem is true" in a paper.

Comment: Thanks. Are you implying that, by today's standards and for something as scrutinised as this, 'accepted' can only be understood to already implicitly contain 'completely, utterly, totally'? (Or, I think not primarily, are you describing mathematicians' etiquette in general?) I only ask because the answer (v1) doesn't go into _degrees of belief in a proof_ (which is hinted at in the question) and it doesn't quite make clear _why_ it doesn't or needn't (in general or for the case of FLT). Could you possibly expand your answer a bit, so that I too can see why (and not just the agreeing upvoters)?

Comment: The proof has been around for 20 years; many very capable mathematicians have studied it in detail, without any coming up with an objection. Sorry, I don't have any coherent thoughts at the present time about "degree of belief in a proof" in general.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer the following (tangential) question.

> Is there even such a thing as a degree of belief in a proof?

There is such a thing as degree of belief in a *theorem*. For example, suppose $T$ is a sentence in the language of set theory expressing a principle of arithmetic. Then if a computer verifies that there is a proof of $T$ from the axioms of $\mathrm{ZFC}$, we can say: "We are $\mathrm{ZFC}$-confident in $T$." Meaning that if $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is sound with respect to arithmetic, then $T$ must actually be *true*.

The problem, of course, is that present-day mathematics isn't actually formalized and proved from explicitly given axioms. So we cannot (currently) make such statements about, say, Fermat's Last Theorem.